# File Upload Endpoint on ASP.NET web api corrupts file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api, file-upload

I'm using .Net Framework 4.7 ASP.NET Web Api

After uploading the files to the endpoint, I noticed the files are corrupted.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task UploadFile([FromODataUri] string key)
    {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

       var provider = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider());
       var file = provider.Contents.Single();

       //get a corrupted file + size of file has increased significantly
       var fileBytes = await file.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

    }
```

*I Also tried working with ReadAsStreamAsync and then read all the bytes, but looks like the data is still changed...

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks,
Adi.

Comment: Nothing in this code snippet. Whatever is going wrong is happening after you ReadAsByteArrayAsync. You can verify by, immediately after this last line, calling File.WriteAllBytes("c:\\Somefile.Whatevs", fileBytes); and examining the file.

Comment: There's no such thing as ".NET Framework 7".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Owin Handler is the responsible for the errors.
No solution were until now. Just a recommendation to not bother with it and just create another service for file uploads.
good luck,
Still waiting for answer btw.